# What is the purpose of Datasources (under Setting) in habitat project?

Tags: helix

What is the purpose of Datasources (under Setting) in habitat project? I searched for many datasources but didn't find any items where these are linked.

Answer (score 2):

Datasources folder under Settings contains a list of datasource configuration items for the existing datasources.

These datasource configuration items don't have any references to them.

For example:

Carousel datasource configuration item specifies where all carousel datasource items exits in sitecore. In this case : `/sitecore/content/Habitat/Global/Media` and what kind of datasource template.

This makes it easier to find/manage datasources in future.

Comment: Thanks Dheeraj but I still don't understand the benefit of keeping something in content tree if we are not using that.

Comment: Like i said above, even though they don't have any reference to them, its easier for content editors or developers to find datasource locations based on these datasource configuration items.

Answer (score 2):

The Datasource Configuration items enable *site-specific* configuration of datasource template and datasource location for renderings shared between sites.

OOTB Sitecore functionality lets you configure a rendering setting the "Datasource Location" to a specific path in Sitecore and "Datasource Template" to a specific template. This means the datasource for that rendering can use only items of one specific template (or descendants) from one specific location (or below that location).

This is not very flexible and means that if you define a rendering within a Habitat Feature layer module, it cannot reference a datasource template or location from anything outside of that module.

In Habitat, the Datasource Configuration items enable you to configure a module's rendering per site. Take the FAQ module as an example. Say we have "Site A" and "Site B" in our project layer.

For "Site A" we might want our FAQ datasources to be under:

```
/sitecore/content/SiteA/Global/FAQ
```

using the following template as its datasource:

```
/sitecore/templates/Project/SiteA/Content Types/FAQ
```

For "Site B" we might want our FAQ datasources to be under:

```
/sitecore/content/SiteB/Global/FAQ
```

using the following template as its datasource:

```
/sitecore/templates/Project/SiteB/Content Types/FAQ
```